# AFCI will not trip

Tags: receptacle, basement

I installed the AFCI breaker as per Code. The tester Klein tool RT310 shows correct wiring but when I press the AFCI switch, the breaker does not trip.

This only happens to one of the 4 arc fault breakers I installed. When I press the AFCI test button on the tool it keeps flashing.

Comment: Possible the breaker is defective, if only one out of four.  Any instructions for flashing lights?

Comment: Code doesn't tell you how to install devices, in 110.3 it requires you follow the instructions and labeling of the device (which UL approved). When you installed the arc fault breakers, did you install the neutral wire according to the instructions?  Neutral handling on an AFCI is not like a regular breaker... *unless it is*, and this varies by model.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica   OP says they installed 4 AFCI breakers, but only one is not acting like the other three.  Can imagine this was the first one OP installed and maybe made a mistake, but seems weird.

Comment: AFCI testers outside the breaker test button are considered unreliable/not a valid test of the AFCI (much more so than even for GFCIs).  What make/model are the AFCIs in question, and does the TEST button on the AFCI in question trip it?

Comment: Breaker is Siemens Type QAF2. Pressing the button on the breaker trips the breaker. Even If the test outside the breaker is not reliable, the inspector is relying on his tester.

Comment: Yesterday, I called an licensed electrician . Everything looks good. He said , the cable might be bad. I was like , may be we are using a red thicker wire with a 15 amp breaker. So we connected a one foot red cable to the breaker and an outlet on the end , it did not trip either. So i decided to change the red wiring with a regular indoor wire. Today i cut the drywall and ran the white wire all across. Same result, the S*B,  does not trip. Wasted money time and cutting drywall did not work. Feels like blowing up the whole house.

Comment: It was the breaker.  I changed it and everything started working. Don't know why it did not work when he swap it with a good one. He must have made a mistake in testing.